# Max/Msp Past object in C++ (increment a value when a threshold is passed)

Tags: c++, triggers, max, counter, increment

I come from Max/Msp which got an object called "past", which increment a variable when a threshold is exceeded. (like a trigger)

I'd like to do the same in C++, but I don't know how to...

For exemple, I'd like to make x a variable and y a counter : when x>100, y=y+1;

I've tried this, but it doesn't work :

```
x++;
cout << "x = " << x << endl;
if (x>100){bang=1;}
cout << "bang = " << bang << endl;
if(bang == !bang){y++;}
cout << "y = " << y << endl;
if (y > 0){cout << "done" << endl; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all bang == !bang will always be false (considering a cast to boolean, when bang is 1 is considered true, !bang will be false so it won't be equal).

If you want to use the inverse bitwise of a number, you have the tilda operator  "~"

There are many ways to create triggers, but the simplest way which fits your need should look something like the following :

```
static bool triggerFired=false;
void runLoop(int curX, int &yRef)
{
    curX++;
    if (curX > 100 && !triggerFired)
    {
        triggerFired = true;
        yRef++;
    } 
}
```

The static boolean value has the purpose to make the trigger fire only once, and not each time after x > 100 .